# Linux file permissions for selected users to access/create/delete folders (FreeNAS)

Tags: linux, ftp, file-permissions, freenas

I'm stuck on setting up FTP read/write file permissions (running FreeNAS). The read/write permissions for each user can follow the current format:

1. Users can read from all folders they have access to
2. Users can only write to/delete from their own user folders and any newly created folders.
3. Make it so that only `uberuser1` and `uberuser2` can create or delete folders.

Here I know how to handle #1 and #2 but I have no idea if #3 is possible when #2 will occur.

And all rest of my problem below for the FTP (on ProFTPD) directory which looks like:

```
/

- Main_Folder_1
-- user1
-- user2
-- user3
-- uberuser1
-- uberuser2

- Main_Folder_2
-- user4
-- user5
-- uberuser1
-- uberuser2
```

1. Users `uberuser1` and `uberuser2` should have access to /, as well as both the `Main_Folder_1` and `Main_Folder_2` folders.
2. When `users1` to `user3` log in, they should start inside the `Main_Folder_1` folder. They should not be aware that there is a `Main_Folder_2` folder at all, nor should they be able to navigate up into /.
3. Similarly, when user `user4` or `user5` logs in, he should start
   inside the `Main_Folder_2` folder. They should not be aware that
   there is a `Main_Folder_1` folder either, nor should he be able to
   navigate up into /.

No. 1 - no problem but how to get #2 and #3? I can create new groups `MF1` and `MF2` for each of those users which will limit access to those folders but how can I set chroot for them to their main folders when after log in to the FTP they are landing into `/` folder and see both main folders?

I have heard that my problem can by tackled by creating datasets in FreeNAS but I was not able to find any similar example how to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have got it to work in 99%

First I have created groups: `MF`, `MF1` and `MF2`. Then I have added all users including uberusers to the `MF` group. Next `user1` through `user3` where added to the `MF1` group then `user4` and `user5` to the `MF2` group.

I have set permissions for `Main_Folder_1` and `Main_Folder_2` to be sure belongs to the `MF` group.

Next step it was editing `proftpd.conf` file to be sure users are chrooted to selected folders. Edited lines were

```
DefaultRoot ~ !wheel !MF1 !MF2
DefaultRoot ~/Main_Folder_1 MF1
DefaultRoot ~/Main_Folder_2 MF2
```

After FTP service restart I had working restricted users to selected folders.